# current session user not displaying in razorpages

Tags: c#, authentication, session, razor

i have a super basic logic page in razorpages
I am using sessions to save current user login credentials into a user model, i wanna display it after, but even though the currentuser isnt null, the currentuser.Name is empty for some reason

here is the code:
***Index.cshtml.cs***

```
public User currentUser { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string LoginUserName { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
    public void OnPostLogin()
    {
        currentUser = new(LoginUserName.ToString(),LoginPassword.ToString());
        HttpContext.Session.SetObjectsession("currentUser", currentUser);

    }
```

***Index.cshtml*** 
**Here it should display @reuslt.Name, but it displays just the "works" label that is checking if it goes into the right if**

```
<form method="post" class="LoginContainer">
<label style="color:grey; font-size:17px; margin-left:20px;">Uživatelské jméno</label>
<input name="LoginUserName" class="LoginUsername" type="text"/>
<label style="color:grey; font-size:17px; margin-left:20px;">Heslo</label>
<input name="LoginPassword" class="LoginPassword" type="text" />
<input type="submit" class="Prihlasit" value="Přihlásit" asp-page-handler="Login"/>
@{
    var reuslt = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentUser");
}

@if (reuslt != null)
{
    <h1>@reuslt.Name</h1>
    <h1>works</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>current user is null</h1>
}
```

***TestSession.cs***

```
public static class TestSession
{
    //set session
    public static void SetObjectsession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    //get session
    public static T GetObjectsession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

i found the mistake, it was a very easy fix.
In my model class i haven't saved the constructor sent variables into the User model variables

```
public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public User(string name, string password)
    {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
    }
```

Sorry for unnecesary question